# rewriting console.log to $('body').append

Tags: jquery

I got this from [Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/),

```
window.log = function(){
  if(this.console){
    console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) );
  }
};
```

Q: For displaying **objects and arrays** on the page instead of the console, how can this be rewritten to use $('body').append instead of console.log?

Comment: The tricky thing here is that `arguments` is an array of values, some of which could be objects or arrays.  If an array comes in with 4 values, 2 of which are strings, and 2 of which are arrays, do the strings get written to the console and the arrays to the body, or is it all or nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.log = function() {
    $(document.body).append(JSON.stringify(Array().slice.call(arguments)));
};
```

This will render strings, arrays and object literals

And the amended one to stop [] brackets appearing and to add br tag 
If you call it with multiple arguments you will get a br for each argument.

```
window.log = function() {
  $.each(arguments, function(i, a) {
    $(document.body).append('<br/>' + JSON.stringify(a));
  });
};
```

Comment: James, this is getting better, but I need something that says if (isArray(a)) {for (i=0;i<a.length;i++)...

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but this should be close:

```
window.log = function(){
  $(document.body).append(JSON.stringify(arguments));
};
```

Comment: Sounds like he wants to show the objects/arrays on the body INSTEAD OF console.log, not in the case where console is unavailable.

Comment: `$.parseJSON` parses a JSON string into an object &mdash; I think you want the reverse of that, `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Is $(document.body) faster than $('body')?  Is that why it's used?

Comment: Ouch, good catch Andy. And @Philip, I'm not sure, it's just always how I've done it.